# NSolve cannot find the solution

Tags: equation-solving

I have some data which looks like:

```
Tdata = {{0., 0.05}, {0.78125, 0.05}, {1.5625, 0.15}, {2.34375, 0.}, {3.125, 
0.}, {3.90625, 0.1}, {4.6875, 0.15}, {5.46875, 0.05}, {6.25, 
0.}, {7.03125, 0.1}, {7.8125, 0.05}, {8.59375, 0.1}, {9.375, 
0.1}, {10.1563, 0.2}, {10.9375, 0.25}, {11.7188, 0.4}, {12.5, 
0.55}, {13.2813, 0.45}, {14.0625, 0.7}, {14.8438, 0.95}, {15.625, 
1.}, {16.4063, 1.8}, {17.1875, 2.}, {17.9688, 2.3}, {18.75, 
2.05}, {19.5313, 2.6}, {20.3125, 3.4}, {21.0938, 4.1}, {21.875, 
4.8}, {22.6563, 4.8}, {23.4375, 5.75}, {24.2188, 6.3}, {25., 
6.45}, {25.7813, 7.15}, {26.5625, 8.8}, {27.3438, 8.6}, {28.125, 
9.25}, {28.9063, 10.35}, {29.6875, 12.1}, {30.4688, 10.6}, {31.25, 
11.6}, {32.0313, 12.7}, {32.8125, 12.6}, {33.5938, 12.75}, {34.375, 
15.3}, {35.1563, 13.25}, {35.9375, 12.35}, {36.7188, 12.65}, {37.5, 
14.1}, {38.2813, 13.5}, {39.0625, 12.5}, {39.8438, 13.6}, {40.625, 
12.4}, {41.4063, 11.15}, {42.1875, 10.65}, {42.9688, 11.3}, {43.75, 
11.45}, {44.5313, 9.95}, {45.3125, 10.4}, {46.0938, 10.45}, {46.875,
8.85}, {47.6563, 9.6}, {48.4375, 8.4}, {49.2188, 8.5}, {50., 
8.05}, {50.7813, 7.9}, {51.5625, 6.95}, {52.3438, 6.85}, {53.125, 
6.2}, {53.9063, 6.6}, {54.6875, 6.6}, {55.4688, 5.25}, {56.25, 
5.45}, {57.0313, 5.35}, {57.8125, 4.5}, {58.5938, 4.1}, {59.375, 
3.6}, {60.1563, 3.5}, {60.9375, 2.95}, {61.7188, 3.05}, {62.5, 
3.1}, {63.2813, 3.15}, {64.0625, 2.85}, {64.8438, 2.35}, {65.625, 
2.15}, {66.4063, 3.1}, {67.1875, 2.5}, {67.9688, 1.95}, {68.75, 
2.45}, {69.5313, 2.}, {70.3125, 1.95}, {71.0938, 1.9}, {71.875, 
1.35}, {72.6563, 1.2}, {73.4375, 1.}, {74.2188, 1.05}, {75., 
1.5}, {75.7813, 1.05}, {76.5625, 1.2}, {77.3438, 1.05}, {78.125, 
0.95}, {78.9063, 0.85}, {79.6875, 0.7}, {80.4688, 1.05}, {81.25, 
0.9}, {82.0313, 0.65}, {82.8125, 0.85}, {83.5938, 0.65}, {84.375, 
0.8}, {85.1563, 0.6}, {85.9375, 0.65}, {86.7188, 0.4}, {87.5, 
0.55}, {88.2813, 0.7}, {89.0625, 0.45}, {89.8438, 0.55}, {90.625, 
0.35}, {91.4063, 0.5}, {92.1875, 0.45}, {92.9688, 0.3}, {93.75, 
0.15}, {94.5313, 0.3}, {95.3125, 0.3}, {96.0938, 0.35}, {96.875, 
0.15}, {97.6563, 0.2}, {98.4375, 0.3}, {99.2188, 0.15}, {100., 
0.3}, {100.781, 0.2}, {101.563, 0.25}, {102.344, 0.45}, {103.125, 
0.1}, {103.906, 0.1}, {104.688, 0.05}, {105.469, 0.3}, {106.25, 
0.1}, {107.031, 0.25}, {107.813, 0.05}, {108.594, 0.15}, {109.375, 
0.05}, {110.156, 0.1}, {110.938, 0.1}, {111.719, 0.05}, {112.5, 
0.}, {113.281, 0.2}, {114.063, 0.05}, {114.844, 0.1}, {115.625, 
0.05}, {116.406, 0.05}, {117.188, 0.1}, {117.969, 0.25}, {118.75, 
0.1}, {119.531, 0.1}, {120.313, 0.}, {121.094, 0.05}, {121.875, 
0.05}, {122.656, 0.05}, {123.438, 0.}, {124.219, 0.05}, {125., 
0.05}, {125.781, 0.}, {126.563, 0.}, {127.344, 0.1}}
```

[image]

I tried to fit this data to a series of polynomials:

```
sol = Fit[Tdata, Table[x^i, {i, 0, 14}], x]
plot1 = Plot[sol, {x, 1, 120}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.005]}, 
PlotRange -> All];
Show[{plot1, plot}]

0.180145 - 0.202127 x + 0.0517504 x^2 - 0.000786656 x^3 - 
0.000942415 x^4 + 0.000123705 x^5 - 7.22477*10^-6 x^6 + 
2.44885*10^-7 x^7 - 5.32789*10^-9 x^8 + 7.78619*10^-11 x^9 - 
7.75517*10^-13 x^10 + 5.20728*10^-15 x^11 - 2.25919*10^-17 x^12 + 
5.72595*10^-20 x^13 - 6.4449*10^-23 x^14
```

[image]

I know that this data, which obtained experimentally, is the convolution of a Gaussian

function and an exponential.

```
numberOFexp = 1;

model[z_] := Sum[Subscript[a, i]*Exp[-z/Subscript[\[Tau], i]], {i, 1, numberOFexp}] ;

irf[z_] := (2.0*Sqrt[2*Log[2]])/(\[CapitalDelta]*Sqrt[2.0*Pi])*Exp[-4.0*Log[2]*
((z -\[Mu])/\[CapitalDelta])^2];

model2 = Integrate[irf[z]*model[t - z], {z, 0, t}](*This is what generates the exprimentall data*)
```

Now, I expand `model2` up to the powers by which I fitted the data with polynomials. The point is that in the `model2` there are some parameters which I want to know. I had fitted the data with a polynomial with 15 terms. I want to expand `model2` up to 15 terms and equate the coefficient of each polynomial of my fit to this expansion and get those unknown parameters. Because I have just 4 unknown I decided to expand `model2` up to 4 term.
I tried:

```
model3 = Normal[Series[model2, {t, 36, 3}]];

unknowns= CoefficientList[model3, t];
co2 = CoefficientList[sol, x];
co3 = co2[[1 ;; 4]]
NSolve[unknowns==co3 , {\[CapitalDelta], \[Mu], Subscript[\[Tau], 1], Subscript[a, 1]}, Reals]
```

However, this can't find the solution.

Comment: Several items are not defined, such as `co` and `Tdata` and `plot`. Also it is not entirely clear (to me at least) what it is you want.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. I edited the code. `Tdata` is `data` which I introduced first.`plot` is the plot of the `Tdata`.

Comment: If you know that your data is a convolution of Gaussian and exponential, I'd suggest that you take a look at the procedure I proposed in this older answer of mine, which recovers the parameters of the exponential directly: [List Deconvolution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110029/27951).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List Deconvolution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110016/list-deconvolution)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP appears to have found the bugs in his code and has abandon the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = Tdata;  (* OP changed variable in question *)
numberOFexp = 1;

model[z_] := Sum[a[i]*Exp[-z/tau[i]], {i, 1, numberOFexp}];

irf[z_] := (2.0*Sqrt[2*Log[2]])/(delta*Sqrt[2.0*Pi])* Exp[-4.0*Log[2]*((z - mu)/delta)^2];

model2 = Integrate[irf[z]*model[t - z], {z, 0, t}];
fit = FindFit[data, model2, {delta, mu, tau[1], a[1]}, {t}]
modelf = Function[{t}, Evaluate[model2 /. fit]];
Plot[modelf[t], {t, 0, 128}, Epilog -> Map[Point, data]]
Panel[TableForm[CoefficientList[Series[modelf[t], {t, 0, 14}], t], 
                TableHeadings -> {Range[0, 14], {"Coeff"}}], "Coefficients"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I did not want the coefficient of the expansion of the fit. I already had them. I needed to know tau1,a1 delta, and mu. I looked at your code and your `FindFit` code notice a mistake in my code. In my code I had included a constraint for the variables I wanted to know. However, there was a typo and so there could not be a solution. Even after correcting the typo, I realized that having constraint on my unknowns causes underflow. Finally, without any constraint I got the unknowns I wanted.